# How to check if re.sub() has successfully replaced in python?

Tags: python, regex

Since `re.sub()` returns the whole modified/unmodified string, is there any way to check if `re.sub()` has successfully modified the text, without searching the output of `re.sub()`?

Comment: Why wouldn't it replace correctly. You can check the string for the regex with `re.match()`before if you want to know if there are any matches inside.

Comment: I assumed the question meant: "how can you tell if re.sub() makes substitutions or not"

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Padraic : thought of printing message like "substitution success"  after validating re.sub() in a "if" condition.

Answer (score 52):

You can use [`re.subn`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.subn) which perform the same operation as sub(), but return a tuple (new_string, number_of_subs_made)

If number of modification is `0`  i.e. string is not modified.

```
>>> re.subn('(xx)+', '', 'abcdab')
('abcdab', 0)
>>> re.subn('(ab)+', '', 'abcdab')
('cd', 2)
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen,this gives info about the modification.

Answer (score 8):

If you have the following code:

```
import re
s1 = "aaa"
result = re.sub("a", "b", s1)
```

You can check if the call to sub made subsitutions by comparing the id of result to s1 like so:

```
id(s1) == id(result)
```

or, which is the same:

```
s1 is result
```

This is because strings in python are immutable, so if any substitutions are made, the result will be a different string than the original (ie: the original string is unchanged). The advantage of using the ids for comparison rather than the contents of the strings is that the comparison is constant time instead of linear.

Comment: Cannot understand the downvotes. I confirmed this to work. This is even documented: "If the pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged". Well, it doesn't explicitly say "the same object", so it _might_ break sometime, but if the OP is dead set on avoiding comparison, this is the best we can offer.

Comment: `re.sub(s1, "a", "b")` makes no sense in the context of your answer

Comment: Padric, thanks I've changed the answer to reflect this

Comment: Well, didn't know about `subn` in the other answer (because I didn't ever need it), that one is definitely the "one obvious way". This one is still worthy of the "second prize".